# Notice: Undefined index: page nothing helps register

Tags: php, html

I know that there are a few Threads to this Problem but until now nothing changed. 
My code Looks like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="RegisterPage">
  <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Register</h1>
      </div>
  <div data-role="content">
  <?php
  if(!isset($_GET["page"])){
  ?>
  <form action="register.php?page=2" method="post">
    Username:<input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" /><br />
    Password:<input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password" /><br />
    Repeat Password:<input type="text" name="pw2" placeholder="Repeat Password" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<?php
  }
  if(!isset($_GET["page"])){
      if($_GET["page"] == "2") {
          $user = strtolower($_POST["user"]);
          $pw = md5($_POST["pw"]);
          $pw2 = md5($_POST["pw2"]);

          if($pw != $pw2 ){
              echo $pw;
              echo " The Passwords are diffrent! Please try again..<a href=\"register.php \">Back</a>";
          }
      }
  }
  ?>
```

When I type anything in the form the code sends me to a page where only the Header is displayed. Nothing else happend.

Maybe im blind of anything but I can´t find the Problem.

Comment: In both if, you checked `!isset`, change your second if to `isset`

Comment: you have to change `if(!isset($_GET["page"])){` to `if(isset($_GET["page"])){` the second time

Answer (score 0):

Fix the error :

```
if(isset($_GET["page"])){  // error in this line
      if($_GET["page"] == "2") {
          $user = strtolower($_POST["user"]);
          $pw = md5($_POST["pw"]);
          $pw2 = md5($_POST["pw2"]);

          if($pw != $pw2 ){
              echo $pw;
              echo " The Passwords are diffrent! Please try again..<a href=\"register.php \">Back</a>";
          }
      }
  }
```

`if(isset($_GET["page"]))` instead of `if(!isset($_GET["page"]))`

Comment: whoops didnt see your  answer :P

Answer (score 0):

this is the whole corrected code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="RegisterPage">
      <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Register</h1>
          </div>
      <div data-role="content">
      <?php
      if(!isset($_GET["page"])){
      ?>
      <form action="register.php?page=2" method="post">
        Username:<input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" /><br />
        Password:<input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password" /><br />
        Repeat Password:<input type="text" name="pw2" placeholder="Repeat Password" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <?php
      }
      if(isset($_GET["page"])){ //error was here with !isset(). you did that 2 times
          if($_GET["page"] == "2") {
              $user = strtolower($_POST["user"]);
              $pw = md5($_POST["pw"]);
              $pw2 = md5($_POST["pw2"]);

              if($pw != $pw2 ){
                  echo $pw;
                  echo " The Passwords are diffrent! Please try again..<a href=\"register.php \">Back</a>";
              }
          }
      }
      ?>
```